# How can I find a county fips given a yahoo woeid

Tags: county

I've used the Yahoo API to pull some woeids for counties.  I need to map those woeids back to fips codes in order to associate them back to other data in my database, but I can't seems to figure out how to get a fips given a woeid.

Yahoo's [concordance API](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/guide/api-reference.html#api-concordance) handles the other direction.  With that, I can get a woeid for a given fips code, but how do I go the other direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't the lists at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_county_code work?  That is, from weoid you can get county and state name and then look up the FIPS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the YQL console to find all kinds of concordance for a given WOEID, eg. for Austria the query is 'select * from geo.concordance where namespace="woeid" and text="23424750"', try the following link and click the 'TEST' button.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20geo.concordance%20where%20namespace%3D%22woeid%22%20and%20text%3D%2223424750%22

Comment: Dang it, I could have sworn I tried that.  Works great though.  Thanks!

Comment: Using YQL you can find all available concordance for a country searching by any namespace, eg. you can match FIPS by WOEID, find WOEID for given ISO 3166, and so on, it's interchangeable. At different levels such as states and towns you can find UN locodes, OSM codes and so on. For airports you can find FAA, IATA and ICAO codes, too much fun :)

Answer (score 1):

You can go the other way with /concordance/fips/{id} according to http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/guide/api-reference.html#api-concordance. Whether this helps probably depends on how many fips labelled objects you have.

Comment: According to that documentation, the concordance behaves as @Tristan states: *to* woeids, not *from* woeids: "Returns information that maps identifiers (codes) from other providers to WOEIDs."

Comment: That's what I said - if he doesn't have many counties to process it might work out.